# Can't set headers after they are sent: Where do I put the final response?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm hoping for a little guidance here. Basically, I have a mondodb (via mongoose) that has brands, products, and locale customization tables.

I do a search for all products for a specific brand, then I query the locale customization table to see if those products have custom names based on the locale. If they do, then I'd like to replace the productName with the custom name.

Now, if I call a subset of products that have custom names with the code below, then I get the correct response with the changed name in the response.

If I call a subset that doesn't have custom name(s), then I get the dreaded "Can't set headers after they are sent." message.

I understand why I can't send headers twice, but I can't seem to find out how to build the correct response and send it. I've put the response everywhere I can think of - set variables (that don't carry over) and basically pulled out my hair the past few days. Unfortunately I can't change the master brand or product data (it's read only), so I'm stuck doing this lookup.

Below is my simplified schema and code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
productsSchema = {
    active: String,
    brandName: String,
    productName: String,
    code: String
    locale: String
}
localeCustomizationsSchema = {
    locale: String,
    products: [{
        productCode: String,
        productCode: String
    }]
}
router.get('/products/:locale/:code', function(req, res) {
    products.findOne({
        active: "true",
        locale: req.params.locale,
        code: req.params.code
    }, {
        brandName: 1,
        _id: 0
    }, function(err, brand) {
        if(err) return res.send(err)
        if(!brand) return res.send(JSON.stringify({
        'Error': 'No products found for code ' + req.params.code
        }))
        products.find({
            active: "true",
            locale: req.params.locale,
            brandName: brand.brandName
        }, {
            productName: 1,
            productCode: 1,
            _id: 0
        }, function(err, products) {
            if(err) return res.send(err)
            async.map(products, function(product, next) {
                localecustomizations.findOne({
                    locale: req.params.locale,
                    'products.productCode': product.productCode
                }, function(err, result) {
                    if(err) return res.send(err)
                    if(result) {
                        product.productName = result.products[0].customName
                        return res.json(products)
                   }
                })
            })
            return res.json(products)
        }).sort({
            productName: 1
        })
     })
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the final callback of `async.map()`, which is where you would send a response (*after* all products have been mapped):

```
async.map(products, function(product, next) {
  localecustomizations.findOne({
    locale: req.params.locale,
    'products.productCode': product.productCode
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    // TODO: make sure `result` and `result.products[0]` actually exist.
    product.productName = result.products[0].customName
    return next(null, product)
  })
}, function(err, products) {
  if (err) return res.send(err);
  return res.json(products);
})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly after some error correction. Thank you, Robert!